Bivariate polynomial factor theorem
I have seen someone make the following statement.
For a polynomial over the real numbers with $f(x,x^2)=0 ~\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can factor it $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)g(x,y)$ for some other polynomial $g$ in two variables over the real numbers. The reasoning that has been given for this is we can view $f$ as a polynomial just in $y$ and via the degree function we get:
$f(x,y)=(y-x^2)g_x(y)+r_x(y)$
Now $r_x$ must be constant for all $x$ and it follows: $0=f(x,x^2)=r_x(x^2)$. Now we get $f(x,y)=(y-x^2)g_x(y)$ as a result. We know that for all $x,$ $g_x$ is a polynomial in $y$ but the statement seems to imply that $g_x$ is a polynomial in $y$ and $x$ which is what seems fishy to me. Why would this be true and if not, can you even factor polynomials in this fashion?
(In the original statement I saw $g_x$ was just written as $g(x,y).$)

This question is similar to: Division by $x-a$ in a polynomial ring $R[x]$. Apply it to $a:=x^2\in R:=\Bbb R[x]$, $f\in R[y]$.

Let $,S = \Bbb R[x].,$ By division with remainder in $S[y]$ we have $,f(y) = (y-x^2)g(y) + r,,$ with $\deg_y(r) < 1,$ so $,r\in S,,$ i.e $,r = r(x)\in \Bbb R[x].,$ Eval'ing at $,y = x^2$ shows $,r(x^2) = 0,$ for all $,r\in \Bbb R,,$ so $,r(x),$ has more roots than its degree, hence $,r,$ is the zero polynomial. $\ \ $

One way to look at the situation is by writing $g(x,y) = f(x,y + x^2)$. Then $g(x,y)$ is a polynomial with $g(x,0) = 0$ for all $x$. Writing $g(x,y) = \sum_{i,j=0}^n a_{ij}x^iy^j$, the statement that $g(x,0) = 0$ is equivalent to saying that $\sum_{ i=0}^n a_{i0}x^i = 0$ for all $x$. This means that each $a_{i0}$ is zero, so that
$$g(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x^iy^j$$
$$=y \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x^iy^{j-1}$$
Thus letting $h(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x^iy^{j-1}$ we have
$$g(x,y) = y \,h(x,y)$$
Now replacing $y$ by $y - x^2$ one has $f(x,y) = g(x,y -x^2) = (y - x^2) h(x,y-x^2)$, which is of the desired form since $h(x,y)$ and therefore $h(x,y - x^2)$ is a polynomial.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.

It's not a duplicate answer. The 12 year old question you linked to has only one answer, and it's different from this one. I do believe there is value in seeing multiple approaches to popular questions. I would like to add that this constant closing of questions because similar ones have been asked before is a disincentive to participating in this site, and in my opinion will harm it in the long run.

The answer duplicates a proof of the factor (or remainder) theorem, i.e. $, y-a\mid f(y),$ if $,f(a)=0\ $  (here $,a  = x^2).,$ Duplicating the proof in this special case  (vs. invoking the theorem  by name as in the linked dupe) greatly complicates comprehension of the essence of the matter.

No, quite the opposite, as many students are more comfortable with a concrete example than an abstract generalization involving rings over a polynomial ring. Also, I am not invoking the remainder theorem; obviously my answer is not the same as the linked one. Please stop this.

The question is tagged abstract-algebra. There we strive to abstract out common algebraic structure (and methods) so they can be efficiently reused in diverse contexts. A beginner reading the above answer will likely have no clue that it is essentially a simple application of the ubiquitous factor or remainder theorem over the coef ring $\Bbb R[x],$ since the proof becomes more complicated when repeated inline in this context. As for "comfortable", even a high school student can understand how to write a polynomial $,g(x,y),$ as a polynomial in $y$ whose coef's are polynomials in $x\ $

I don't actually answer to you, and if I have reasons to think a new answer is warranted, I have the right to give one. You were out of line instructing me not to. Your reasoning is highly unconvincing to me, and I am not willing to discuss the matter any further.
